# Why do C or C++ books not contain anything on networking?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming, ansi-c

I've just been looking at the following books:
-K&R C
-The Complete Reference C++
-The Complete Reference C
-Deitel How to Program C
-Deitel How to Program C++

and not one of them contains any networking, how to create sockets etc. Is there any 'definitive' reference for C network programming? Google wasn't particularly helpful.

I'm probably considering windows and unix platforms

Comment: because C are C++ are programming languages. networking is one such area where they are used.

Comment: "Why do car factory service manuals not contain anything about driving?"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"C books" usually describe the language and the standard library. Sockets aren't in the standard library.

If you want a good book on sockets, [UNP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) by Stevens is arguably the best.

Comment: The Stevens books are widely considered the "Bible" on sockets.

Comment: Also look at the Beej guide on network programming (http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) for a quick overview or tutorial.

Comment: so if i wanted to do socket programming I would have to install a 3rd party library of some sort?

Comment: no - usually your OS comes with necessary library pre-installed...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with cnicutar's answer...

If you need a good starting point - see http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The C/C++ is a language, and the networking is not part of the language, and that is the *why*

If you do

```
   man 2 accept
   man 2 select
   man 2 connect
   man 2 recv
   man 2 send
```

you will see template code and references needed for most of your TCP networking need

Comment: If you're on Linux, of course.

Comment: even if your not on linux, then a google search on "man select" will provide you the man page....

Comment: If you find that overly complicated, then check out ZeroMQ instead. It's a supersocket library based on messages which is much easier to work with than plain low-level sockets.